# Use a Cython extension from a compiled python in php?

Tags: php, python, cython

Can this be done?

No idea if the Cython `.so` extension can be dynamic loaded from a php script or does it needs any extra manage?

Comment: I've removed the [python-3.x] and [python-2.7] tags. If your question is really about a specific version, feel free to re-add one of them.

Comment: Wooble Cython works on both versions, so i set the tags if on one of each version it took something new to export to other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Cython extensions use the Python C API, so they can't be loaded and called directly from PHP. They will typically take and return PyObject structs as arguments (Python objects). You'll need a Python <-> PHP binding to load the .so and do object conversion.

Comment: mm... i see, and is there something like this python -> php binding system outthere?

Comment: There's pip (Python in PHP), but I've never tried it: http://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/